# Why does using request parameter with special character in database query fail to find results, but same string as fixed value work fine?

Tags: python, pymongo, fastapi, urlencode

I'm having an issue with API endpoints where if a database query is sent that contains special characters, like 'ä', the MongoDB doesn't find any data.

```
@router.get("")
def get_something_data(name: Optional[str] = None):
    query = {}

    if name:
        query.update({"Name": re.compile(name, re.IGNORECASE)})

    db = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost:whatever")
    database = db[os.environ["DB_SOMETHING"]]
    collection = database[os.environ["COLL_SOMETHING"]]

    return collection.find(query))
```

If I print the query parameter, it looks just fine. After few hours of debugging I found out that if I force a set value to the query (instead of using a the parameter from the request) it works fine. Like this:

```
@router.get("")
def get_something_data(name: Optional[str] = None):
    query = {}

    if name:
        query.update({"Name": re.compile("Fixed search value with ä", re.IGNORECASE)})

    db = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost:whatever")
    database = db[os.environ["DB_SOMETHING"]]
    collection = database[os.environ["COLL_SOMETHING"]]

    return collection.find(query))
```

I'm suspecting that this is an encoding issue, but I haven't found a way to fix this yet, so I'm coming here to ask for help. This is indeed a strange issue and I haven't seen anyone else have this issue yet.

*Removed no longer relevant edits*

EDIT 3: Okay, so if I format the string coming from the http request with the following:

```
bytes(name, "cp1252").decode("utf-8")
```

And then use that as the query parameter for the db, it works fine. It's a bit hacky way of getting it to work... So my guess is that the http request comes in as `utf-8`, but python reads it as if it was `cp1252`, which messed up the special characters. Not sure why it uses `cp1252`. Based on what I've read, python should use `utf-8` by default. Is there a way to change python to use `utf-8` instead of `cp1252`?

Comment: Did you try outputting the ordinal value of the character in both cases? (`ord(chr)`)

Comment: Clearly, the working and non-working `query` are different.  When you compare them, what is the difference?

Comment: @MatsLindh The `ord` of the `ä` character coming through the endpoint is `195, 164`. Printing the character shows up just fine in console (this one didn't work in the db query). While the `ä` character written directly in the code as string outputs `228` and shows up as � in console (this one works in the db query).